# Centrino Wireless N1030 Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: wireless, 18.04, intel-wireless

I have old Ubuntu machine (HP G6) that I upgraded to 18.04. Unfortunately it seems that the said wireless is not supported. Is there a way to get even legacy drivers to work? I have another modern machine but I love to use that oldie-goodie machine for some other stuffs and wireless make it a pain. Ethernet works fine.

`sudo lshw -class network` does not list the wireless card information.

Comment: I can't help with your answer sorry, but if you have the 18.04 (or 18.04.1) ISO I would write it to a thumb-drive (or dvdr(w)) and boot it, then see if you can get the wireless to work on that... if it works there, finding the difference between that and your system-image will be easier than a now gone 16.04 image (*in my opinion*)

Comment: Why do you think it is not supported? Did you try a live session? In fact, I believe that the driver *iwlwifi* supports it and the needed firmware is included by default in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @chili555 I have upgraded and I cannot get wireless icon available. Only bluetooth. That's why I thought it is not supported

Comment: @guiverc I have already upgraded to 18.04.1 (thanks for your comment, I thought it was 18.04)

Comment: My comment was a suggestion to try and see if wireless was working on the 'live' or install media; not to install anything, but to 'try-ubuntu' and see if wireless works.  If it works there, you have a working config that you can copy to your 18.04.x that you have installed. Same thing Chili555 asked about; using the ISO to create a 'live' media or a 'temporary-second-test-machine' using your actual hardware (but not touching your actual install).  You missed our intended meaning/suggestion.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will try that later. I don't have any USB/DVD here

Comment: Did the correct driver load? `lsmod | grep iwl` Any clues here? `rfkill list all` Or here? `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: `lsmod` and `dmesg` result in empty response. `rfkill` lists only `hci0:Bluetooth...` which I can see. No clue about wireless at all

Comment: I finally found it. It was a hardware issue, see the answer

Answer (score 1):

After tests including the onesposted by @chili555 failed to show any sign of hardware availability, I opened the Computer and tried to tighten all connections going to Wireless card (two actually)and switched on the machine.
The Card was recognized and I'm using it to type this answer.

I appreciate everyone that helped me getting to the answer. As always community around here is great!